# I'm trying to create a ML algorithm to predict ratings for movies using the MovieLens Dataset, but the loss and accuracy always stay the same

Tags: python, machine-learning

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, Adagrad
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from scipy import stats
from keras import regularizers
from keras.layers import Dropout

# load in the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Book11.csv')

# reshaping the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
dataset['rating'] = scaler.fit_transform(dataset['rating'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

# remove outliers
z = np.abs(stats.zscore(dataset))
dataset = dataset[(z < 3).all(axis=1)]

# initializing the X and Y variable
x = dataset.drop(columns=['rating'])
y = dataset['rating']

# initialise training and testing sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

# creating the model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# reshape input data for a conv2d layer
x_train = np.reshape(x_train.values, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1, 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test.values, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1, 1))

# create the model
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                 input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1, 1), activation='relu',
                                 padding='same', strides=(1, 1),
                                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))


# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100)

# evaluate the model
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

There are 100k data entries in the data so I don't think the size of the dataset is the problem.

I've messed around with regularization, dropout, learning rate and the complexity of the model, but no matter what I do, the accuracy and loss always stay around ~0.4800 throughout each epoch of the model. How can I improve my model or make changes to make it improve accuracy and decrease loss over time?

Comment: Generally it's not a good idea to use ReLU as activation for the last layer. That might be where the problem is. Just to be sure, what kind of output is it?

Comment: By that I mean what's the format of the label, like, is it 1 to 5 stars?

Comment: @FelixFourcolor the output label is a value from 0 to 1, which is from reshaping the initial 1-5 rating. I assume this means the label is multi-class? However when I tried softmax and sigmoid in the final activation function, I still get the same problem where the loss and accuracy don't change.

Answer (score 1):

The model you built was basically a regression model. Given that the output ranges from 1 to 5, and the loss you specified was `"mean_squared_error"`, the loss of 0.48 (what you mistook for accuracy -- there is no accuracy metrics currently in your model) is actually not that bad.

But of course a classifier model is better for the task. Here are things to do.

1. One-hot-encode the labels. This converts a single value from 1 to 5 into an 5-size array. For example, `[4]` becomes `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
y = encoder.fit_transform(y).toarray()
```

2. For the last layer, give it 5 units and use `"softmax"` activation.

```
model.add(Dense(5, activation="softmax"))
```

3. Use correct loss and metrics. For classifier model, the loss should be `"categorical_crossentropy"` and metrics should be `"accuracy"`.

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics="accuracy")
```

Comment: When I try to one-hot-encode the labels, I get the error that it expects a 2D array, but got a 1D array instead. How can I change the input data to be a 2D array?

Comment: Call `reshape(-1, 1)` before one-hot-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

As @Felix_Fourcolor mentioned in the comment, the last layer should be another one to generate an appropriate value of loss.

Think about it, the ReLU calculates the output of model every single layer in range (0, max). Therefore, if you do that as your last layer, the gap between the prediction and target would be so huge, which makes the trouble.

Therefore, you should change the activation function to another.

```
#if your classification is for distinguishing binary-classes.
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

#if your classification is for distinguishing multi-classes.
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: I tried both but I get the same issue, I assume the classification is multi-class due to the output label being 0 to 1, which I got from reshaping the initial 1-5 rating. However, trying both changes still makes the loss and accuracy stay the same throughout.

Comment: @DanielPerson Can I ask why do you have only one Conv2 layer? In DNN, just one Conv2d cannot do anything because only one Conv2d can't learn any feature from your input dataset. My question is why do you have this construction of your model. Just refer to some reference or created yourself?

Comment: I created this myself as im trying to learn ML, I wasn't aware that DNN needed more than one Conv2D layers, if I were to implement more, would I change the hyperparameters of them?

Comment: @DanielPerson It's a good attempt to learn this field by creating the model yourself. To make your course better, I explain the basic of concept in this field by adding a new answer (Because this comment would be so long if I explain its details).

Answer (score 0):

-New Answer-

Lenet is an initial Convolution neural network to create the concept of CNN. This architecture is like:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(6, 5, activation='tanh', input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(2))
model.add(layers.Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, 5, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(2))
model.add(layers.Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(120, 5, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(84, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 28, 28, 6)         156       
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d (AveragePo (None, 14, 14, 6)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 14, 14, 6)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 10, 10, 16)        2416      
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_1 (Average (None, 5, 5, 16)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 5, 5, 16)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 1, 120)         48120     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 120)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 84)                10164     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                850       
=================================================================
Total params: 61,706
Trainable params: 61,706
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I referred to this [article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/lenet-with-tensorflow-a35da0d503df) to create the summary of model.

So, why do we this? There is better explanation for this (refer to the below references that I mention.), so to sum it up, as input data passes the Conv2D, the layer extracts some features from the input. And these features have different characteristics each layer because the shape of an input image is decreasing. Note that each Conv2D layers have a different feature.

[This](https://vinodsblog.com/2020/05/03/role-of-convolutional-layer-in-cnn/) is a good material to understand what a role of convolutional layer is. Also, [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/niranjanjagannath/lenet-5-architecture-for-mnist-using-tensorflow) is a good reference to try yourself.